# IntelliJ - Git integration, cannot run test classes

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea

I'm working on a project to create a few classes relating to a game and testing the classes with various methods. Anyhow my code can't be run with my IntelliJ client. The Run-button is greyed and trying to run by other means (like the run button next to the test in the class) don't work, nothing happens.

I started this project in IntelliJ with Git, the src folder wasn't a source root folder to begin with just an ordinary folder but I changed that so that IntelliJ views my classes as classes, so far as I know. I can't figure out why this is happening, I'm not very experienced with IntelliJ I normally use Eclipse but trying to run that with Git was an even bigger nightmare. I'd really appreciate a little help with this it's killing me. Also is top-folder(inte_projektarbete) supposed to be a "Module"? Has that got to do with it?

Bonus question: Can I just copy the classes from my local git folder to an ordinary Java-project, edit them, copy back into the git folder and commit/push them back into git and keep the version handling and just forget about all this IDE-Git integration mess?

[My issue, project taken from git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q32LI.png)

Comment: You obvisously have problem with some class that does not compile. What is this problem ? What do you see when you click on "Problems", on the bottom of your screen ?

Comment: The test class is not supposed to compile without errors, I'm supposed to do Test driven development, but now suddenly it does work, I can run classes. However apparantly the IntelliJ IDE is running all classes for some reason. So now I'm getting error about things in another class that are only semi-implemented but I suppose I'll just hide those bits in comments. Strange though that all classes are "run", none of them have a main method they're just objects. And they are not all connected and communicating.